# Binding <Return> to button is not working as expected

Tags: python, button, tkinter, bind

I bound the event `<Return>` to a Button, thinking that this would cause the `command` to be run after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
Button(self.f, text="Print", command=self.Printer).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)
self.button1 = Button(self.f, text="search", command=self.search)
self.button1.bind('<Return>', self.search)
self.button1.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)
```

But it doesn't do anything. What must I do for `self.search` to be run when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but note that the focus must be on the button if you want `Return` to call `self.search()`. You can change the focus from widget to widget by pressing `Tab`. The widget in focus is outlined with a thin black line. You may have to press `Tab` one or more times to move the focus to the button before pressing `Return`.

If you want `Return` to work anywhere in the GUI window, then change

```
self.button1.bind('<Return>', self.search)
```

to

```
root.bind('<Return>', self.search)
```

where `root = tk.Tk()`.

For example, compare `button.bind` with `master.bind` in the code below:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SimpleApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        title = kwargs.pop('title')
        frame = tk.Frame(master, **kwargs)
        frame.grid()
        button = tk.Button(frame, text = 'search', command = self.search)
        button.grid()
        button.bind('<Return>', self.search)
        # uncomment if you want `<Return>` bound everywhere.
        # master.bind('<Return>', self.search)  
    def search(self,*args):
        print('searching...')

def basic():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = SimpleApp(root, title = 'Hello, world')
    root.mainloop()

basic()
```

---

Alternatively, you could use

```
    button.bind('<Return>', self.search)
    button.focus()
```

Doing it this way, pressing `Return` calls `self.search()` only when the button has the focus, but the button gets the focus when the app begins.

---

Regarding the use of `*args` and `**kwargs`:

`**kwargs` allows arbitrary keyword arguments to be passed to `__init__`.

When `**kwargs` is used in a function definition like this:

```
def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
```

and we instantiate `SimpleApp` like this:

```
app = SimpleApp(root, title = 'Hello, world')
```

then Python sets `kwargs` to a dict containing the keyword arguments, e.g. `{'title':'Hello, world'}`. Note that `**kwargs` is Python syntax which can only be used in function definitions and function calls (see below), but `kwargs` itself is just a dict.

`kwargs` is then passed to `Frame`:

```
frame = tk.Frame(master, **kwargs)
```

Now, when **kwargs is used in a function call, the key-value pairs in the `kwargs` dict get expanded so that the above function call is equivalent to

```
frame = tk.Frame(master, title = 'Hello, world')
```

Since `Frame` can take numerous keyword arguments, and I don't know them all and don't wish to enumerate them, it is advantageous to use `**kwargs`. 
Note also that even if new keyword arguments were added to `Frame` at some later date, my code will still work, whereas if I spelled out the keywords explicitly then my code would not automatically "upgrade" if `Frame`'s allowable keywords were to change.

`*args`, similarly, allows you to include arbitrary positional arguments to `search`:

```
def search(self,*args):
```

Python sets `args` to a list containing all the positional arguments sent to `search` when `search` is called.

I used *args here because `self.search` is called with no arguments or one argument.

When you say

```
button = tk.Button(frame, text = 'search', command = self.search)
```

`self.search()` is called with no argumens when the button is clicked. But when you say

```
    button.bind('<Return>', self.search)
```

`self.search(event)` is called with one argument when the `Return` key is pressed. `event` is a [Tkinter.Event](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/events-and-bindings.htm) which has attributes (time, state, type, widget, x, y, etc) which allow you to learn more about what event took place.

Another, perhaps better, way to define `search` would have been

```
def search(self, event = None):
    ...
```

This would have made it clear that `search` may be passed 0 or 1 arguments, and not simply and arbitary number of arguments. It also would have provided easier access to `event` if an event were passed to `search`.

Reference:

- [saltycrane's
  explanation](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/).

Comment: Thanks, now it's more clear for me. Just question what stands those: "**kwargs and *args" for?

Comment: I added an explanation of why I used `**kwargs` and `*args`. If it's too long to read, see [saltcrane's explanation](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/).