# Binding Tkinter button: function takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a simple GUI in python using Tkinter.
I've written it so that when a button is pressed a function (measure) is called.
I'm now trying to bind the Enter key to also carry out this function using:

```
root.bind("<Return>", measure)
```

This gives the error when Enter is pressed:

```
TypeError: measure() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

A quick search tells me that if I give the function the argument (self) then the enter bind will work, however if I do this then the button widget gives the error:

```
TypeError: measure() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)
```

Is there a quick fix for this?
Python beginner, so apologies if this is a really simple question.

```
import datetime
import csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


root = Tk()

winx = 480
winy = 320 

virtual_reading = '1.40mm'        

def measure():
    todays_date = datetime.date.today()

    try:
        get_tool_no = int(tool_no_entry.get())
        if get_tool_no <= 0:
            messagebox.showerror("Try Again","Please Enter A Number")
        else:
            with open("thickness records.csv", "a") as thicknessdb: 
                thicknessdbWriter = csv.writer(thicknessdb, dialect='excel', lineterminator='\r')
                thicknessdbWriter.writerow([get_tool_no] + [todays_date] + [virtual_reading])
            thicknessdb.close()
    except:
           messagebox.showerror("Try Again","Please Enter A Number")
    tool_no_entry.delete(0, END)            

root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE) 
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (winx,winy)) 
root.title("Micrometer Reader V1.0")         

record_button = Button(root,width = 30,
                               height = 8,
                               text='Measure',
                               fg='black',
                               bg="light grey", command = measure)

record_button.place(x = 350, y = 100, anchor = CENTER)

reading_display = Label(root, font=("Helvetica", 22), text = virtual_reading)
reading_display.place(x = 80, y =80)

tool_no_entry = Entry(root)
tool_no_entry.place(x = 120, y = 250, anchor=CENTER)
tool_no_entry.focus_set()

root.bind("<Return>", measure)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding <Return> to button is not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679453/binding-return-to-button-is-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command` calls `measure` without arguments but `bind` calls it with `event` argument so `measure` have to receive this value.

You can use

```
def mesaure(event=None):
```

and it will work with `command` and `bind`

Comment: but if you are using anything related to event, inside the function, it gives error, saying `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'num'`

Comment: @CoolCloud `command` doesn't send `event` so don't use `event`. OR for `bind` write function which uses `event` and for `command` write function which doesn't use `event`. OR check `if even is not None:` and then use `event` and when `event` is `None` then use widget directly. But it would be simpler to access widget directly if you want to use the same function in `bind` and `command`

Answer (score 2):

You used the function `measure` twice, one requires one argument, second requires 0 argument. You should wrap it with lambda:

```
root.bind("<Return>", lambda x: measure())
```